# Unable to concatenate string and number in php

Tags: php

How to concatenate as in the code:

```
<?php

print ( "h".2);
```

It is actually giving error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.2' (T_DNUMBER) in /tmp/a.php on line 3
```

I've checked these [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=concatenate%20number%20and%20string%20php&oq=concate&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2j69i57j69i60l2.2767j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but unfortunately  the solution does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP doesn't like it when you have no space between the `.` and the number (this: `"h".2` - no space).

Three ways to solve this:

```
print ("h" . 2);
```

Or

```
print ("h"."2");
```

Or

```
$n = 2;
print ("h".$n);
```

In the first, simply separate the number from the string concatenation operator with a space.

In the second, wrap the number to make it a string.

In the third, use a variable to hold the number.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

print( "h" . "2");
```

Put number into " " and have a space between dot that is used concatenation

output

> h2

the problem with your solution is that you used `.2` without any space. For PHP `.` has meaning decimal point and not joining string with number (concat) look:

```
print( "h" . .2);
```

this will give

> h0.2

first dot is treated as concatenation and second `.2` as decimal point that translates to `0.2`